# How is the STL set/map internally sorted?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I know that the STL containers like set and map are sorted but how are they actually sorted? What is the underlying structure?

I couldn't find any books about it.

---

I'm a C++ beginner please don't judge me. :)

Comment: `std::map` is usually built on top of a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Comment: @CoryKramer, the linked questions all presume that `std::map` is implemented using a red-black tree.  The question "how is std::map implemented?" is a better fit.

Comment: So both are using the red-black tree? I heard something about the  strict weak ordering criterion

Comment: I took it like the OP asking by how they are sorted ? The answer is by default they use the operator  `<` less than.

Comment: @r3musn0x Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought the same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), it is implementation defined how the sorting is being done. The underlying data structure should sort the elements somehow:

> Internally, the elements in a `map` are always sorted by its key following a specific [strict weak ordering criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) indicated by its internal comparison object (of type Compare).

(same holds for `set`.)

A typical data structure for these containers is [red black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) or a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).